Syslog-ng and \n in message body
I'm using syslog-ng in order to collect fortigate logs.
In some messages that contains the user key if the user is in the format user=DOMAIN\user and the user's name starts with n, the the message is divided in two lines (user= DOMAIN\nora.xxx)
`<189>date=2024-04-22 time=08:07:29 devname="01" devid="FG200ETK18" eventtime=1713766048540009231 tz="+0200" logid="0000000013" type="traffic" subtype="forward" level="notice" vd="WIFI" srcip=1.1.1.1 srcname="111" srcport=50759 srcintf="If1" srcintfrole="lan" srcssid="1" apsn="1" ap="xx" channel=44 radioband="802.11ac" signal=-63 snr=32 user="DOMAIN
ora.xxxx" group="g1" ...`
How this can be solved?
I tried to use some rewriting

Solved like this
rewrite r_nl {
subst("\n(?!(<.*$))","\n",value("MESSAGE"), flags("global"));
};
